# MySQL match against with point in text

Tags: mysql

I want to use MySQL `MATCH AGAINST` to search various columns in a table. One of them is the email address field. Now I'm getting results that I really don't understand.

For example, I want to search for every records that holds 'domain.com' in the email address. So with a LIKE, I would do:

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE email LIKE '%domain.com%'
```

With the MATCH AGAINST I woud do

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE MATCH(email) AGAINST ('*domain.com*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But this returns a lot of crap which is absolutely not has anything to do with 'domain.com'. What am I doing wrong?

Note! I do a match against on several columns, email is just one of it. But this one fails terribly!

Comment: did you try ('+domain.com*'    indstead of *domain ?

Comment: @Thomas, that would mean it must start with `domain.com`.

Comment: are you sure? According to the docu "'+apple +juice'

Find rows that contain both words."   there is nothing about beginning of the string  link to the docu I looked at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.` counts as a word delimiter, so `domain.com` in your text (email field) will be indexed as two separate words, or maybe not if `com` is shorter than the minimum word length. MATCH AGAINST isn't really appropriate here.

Comment: Did you find a solution of your problem?, i'm trying to catch domains that contains some words and it seems that search in fulltext have some limitations and it doesn't work like `LIKE %%`